# How to create a mock installer in NSIS?

Tags: installation, nsis

I want to make a mock installer using NSIS so we can demo what our final install process will look like when it's done.

I've gone through the wizard using the Eclipse plugin to create a classic installer.  I want to add additional screens that have no back-end functionality but that would display a description of the data the user needs to input (such as the path to the JRE), a textbox + browse button to input it, and a next button.   How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exact answer will depend on which user interface you're using.

If you're using the [Modern User Interface](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html), this might be of some help:

```
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_VARIABLE $InstallDirectory
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_VARIABLE $JRE_InstallDirectory
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "Choose JRE Location"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Choose an installation path for the JRE."
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "This program will install the JRE to the following directory.  To use a different path, click Browse and select another directory. Click Next to continue."
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_DESTINATION "JRE Path"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
```

That will display the standard Directory page with all the default text (asking for the installation path of your program) and store it in the $InstallDirectory variable.

The following page will have the same layout but with custom text to ask for the JRE install directory, which will be stored in the $JRE_InstallDirectory variable.  For more information, [see the documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html).

Comment: Got it.  I was getting errors on the line where it sets the MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_VARIABLE, but I eventually figured it out.  Thanks a bunch.